# Making an NSTableView behave like a WPF StackPanel

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, stackpanel, monomac

I'm trying to implement a vertical `StackPanel` equivalent in my MonoMac project and am having trouble figuring it out. I am not using interface builder but creating the controls programmatically (this is a restriction). I tried using a `CollectionView` but all items in that control are sizing to the same height.

Looking around the internet, it seems `NSTableView` is the way to go, but I'm not sure how to do it, especially with C# while using a MonoMac target. `CollectionView` was somewhat more straightforward with the `CollectionViewItem.ItemPrototype` allowing me to create the views I want to render. But with an `NSTableView`, it seems like I can only specify a data source that returns the `NSObject`s I want to display. How do I grab this data and then bind them to the view I want to stick in there?

I would prefer C# code but I'm at a stage where I'll accept any and all help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to get it working. Here is some code for anyone who wants to try it out. Basically, we need to write `NSTableViewDelegate`s for the required functions. This implementation also doesn't cache the controls or anything. The [Cocoa API documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html) mentioned using an identifier to reuse the control, or something, but the identifier field is get-only in MonoMac.

I also ended up implementing my `NSTableViewDelegate` functions in my data-source itself which I am sure is not kosher at all, but I'm not sure what the best practice is.

Here's the data source class:

```
class MyTableViewDataSource : NSTableViewDataSource
{
    private NSObject[] _data;

    // I'm coming from an NSCollectionView, so my data is already in this format
    public MyTableViewDataSource(NSObject[] data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public override int GetRowCount(NSTableView tableView)
    {
        return _data.Length;
    }

    #region NSTableViewDelegate Methods

    public NSView GetViewForItem(NSTableView tableView, NSTableColumn tableColumn, int row)
    {
        // MyViewClass extends NSView
        MyViewClass result = tableView.MakeView("MyView", this) as MyViewClass;
        if (result == null)
        { 
            result = new MyViewClass(_data[row]);
            result.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, tableView.Frame.Width, 100); // height doesn't matter since that is managed by GetRowHeight
            result.NeedsDisplay = true;
            // result.Identifier = "MyView"; // this line doesn't work because Identifier only has a getter
        }

        return result;
    }

    public float GetRowHeight(NSTableView tableView, int row)
    {
        float height = FigureOutHeightFromData(_data[row]); // run whatever algorithm you need to get the row's height
        return height;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And here's the snippet that programmatically creates the table:

```
var tableView = new NSTableView();
var dataSource = new MyTableViewDataSource();

tableView.DataSource = dataSource;
tableView.HeaderView = null; // get rid of header row
tableView.GetViewForItem = dataSource.GetViewForItem;
tableView.GetRowHeight = dataSource.GetRowHeight;

AddSubView(tableView);
```

So, it is not a perfect `StackPanel` because one needs to manually calculate row heights, but it's better than nothing.